# how to implement next and previous buttons in webview?

Tags: android, webview

i'm implemented the project in web-view. it retries the data from sqlite . i need next and previous button in the web-view. if i touch on next button it will display the next record in that database.(previous also )

Thanks,
Vinay

Answer (score 2):

On the top of Webview put two buttons with Next and Previous Arrows.

In the onClick() of Next write the goForward code and in Previous write goBack code as below

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
if(v==btnNext)
{
 if(webView.canGoForward())
{
webView.goForward();
}
}
if(v==btnPrevious)
{
 if(webView.canGoBack())
{
webView.goBack();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, First store all record string array.

```
 String[] str = {"one", "two", "", "three"};

  int record= 0;
   next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                           record =  record +1;
            myWebView.loadData(record[1], "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
        }
    });

previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                           record =  record -1;
            myWebView.loadData(record[1], "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
        }
    });
```

Comment: this is my code

  htmltxt = getIntent().getExtras().getString("detail");
  web.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://not/needed", htmltxt, "", "UTF-8", ""); 
 }
} 

i want to add two buttons next and previous buttons in the below of the code.